# I have to check whether the right click is enable on website or not using selenium with python and if enable return -1 , else return 1

Tags: python, selenium

```
    url = input()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='G:\\VIT\SEM8\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
    print(actionChains.context_click().perform())
    driver.close()
```

i tried this code but `actionChains.context_click().perform()` always return None for both the result. Please suggest me another way with code if possible

Comment: Could you please add some specific of what do you mean by enabled right click. some example of a site with element clickable and not clickable